# Numpy: slicing a volume using a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy volume and a 2D numpy matrix:

```
foo = np.random.rand(20,20,10)
amin = np.argmin(foo, axis=2)
```

i would like to use `amin` variable to slice the volume in the same way `np.min` would do:

```
grid = np.indices(min.shape)
idcs = np.stack([grid[0], grid[1], min])

fmin = foo[idcs[0], idcs[1], idcs[2]]
```

problem is that i can't use `np.min` because i also need the `amin` neighbors for interpolation reasons, something that i would obtain doing:

```
pre  = foo[idcs[0], idcs[1], np.clip(idcs[2]-1, 0, 9)]
post = foo[idcs[0], idcs[1], np.clip(idcs[2]+1, 0, 9)]
```

Is there a more pythonic (nupyic) way to do this without creating an `np.grid`? something like:

```
foo[:,:,amin-1:amin+1]
```

that actually works (i would care about margin handling with an early-padding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.ogrid` instead of `np.indices` to save memory.
`np.ogrid` returns an "open" meshgrid:

```
In [24]: np.ogrid[:5,:5]
Out[24]: 
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])]
```

`ogrid` returns component arrays which can be used as indices
in the same way as one would use `np.indices`.
NumPy will automatically broadcast the values in the open mesh when they are used as indices:

```
In [49]: (np.indices((5,5)) == np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ogrid[:5, :5])).all()
Out[49]: True
```

---

```
import numpy as np
h, w, d = 20, 20, 10
foo = np.random.rand(h, w, d)
amin = np.argmin(foo, axis=2)
X, Y = np.ogrid[:h, :w]
amins = np.stack([np.clip(amin+i, 0, d-1) for i in [-1, 0, 1]])
fmins = foo[X, Y, amins]
```

It's better to store `fmin`, `pre` and `post` in one array, `fmins`,
since some NumPy/Scipy operations (like `argmin` or [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)) may need the values in one array. If, later, you need to operate on the 3 components individually, you can always access them using `fmins[i]` or define

```
pre, fmin, post = fmins
```

Comment: I like your answer, if nobody come up with anything better i will mark as answer

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.clip(amin+i, ...`, so you get `amin - 1, amin, amin + 1`?

Comment: @jdehesa well, it depends on the definiton of pre and post, the way you say is the one i was searching for